# C# JSON return object

Tags: c#, json

I been working on this API that I would like to remove the top element but I am not sure the best way to do it. Do I need to

```
 public CARlinesResponse GetCarslinesResponse (string accessKey)
            CARlinesResponse CAR = new CARlinesResponse();
            CarlineManager cm = new CarlineManager ();
            CarslineReportParameters cr= new CarslineReportParameters ();
            car.lines = GetGuidelineViewModel(cm.GetCarslinesResponse (cr));

           return CAR;
           //return CAR.CARline;
        }
```

Model

```
namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class CARlinesResponse
    {
        public CARline[] CARlines{ get; set; }
    }
```

Output I am looking for

```
[
    {
        "Id": "9c996a94-5a61-42b4-953e-34134f6332b3",
        "Title": "Jeep",
        "Version": "grand cherokee",

    }
]
```

Like to remove the top level cars

```
 {
        "CARline": [
            {
                "Id": "9c996a94-5a61-42b4-953e-34134f6332b3",
                "Title": "Jeep",
                "Version": "grand cherokee"
            }
```

Comment: yeah you should just be able to `return Car.Carline;` - you'd also have to modify your method signature accordingly. Is there a problem when you do that?

Comment: Error cannot convert type Models.CarLine[] to CarLinesResponse.

Comment: as I mentioned - you'd **have to modify your method signature accordingly**. See answer below. Of course any code which calls the method might also need to be changed, it depends what you've implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that returning the `Carline` property, with an appropriately amended method signature, should do the trick.

```
public CARline[] GetCarslinesResponse (string accessKey)
{
  CARlinesResponse Car = new CARlinesResponse();
  CarlineManager cm = new CarlineManager ();
  CarslineReportParameters cr= new CarslineReportParameters ();
  Car.Carlines = GetGuidelineViewModel(cm.GetCarslinesResponse (cr));

  return Car.CARlines;
}
```

Of course any code which calls the method might also need to be changed, it depends what exactly you've implemented.

P.S. It seems you could actually shorten this to

```
public CARline[] GetCarslinesResponse (string accessKey)
{
  CarlineManager cm = new CarlineManager ();
  CarslineReportParameters cr = new CarslineReportParameters ();
  return GetGuidelineViewModel(cm.GetCarslinesResponse (cr));
}
```

and dispense with the CarLinesRepsonse object entirely.

Comment: when I change it to CAR.Carline I get implicitly convert type WS.Car.Model.Carline[] to WEBAPI.Model.CarLineReponse.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, **any code which calls this method might also need to be changed**. You haven't shown that calling code so I can't tell you what exactly to change. But you need to understand that C# is a strongly-typed language - if you're going to call a method, you have to make sure you read the result into a variable of the matching type.

Comment: P.S. Please don't edit your question like that, with no explanation. it makes the comments and answers seem nonsensical. If you have an update, please add it as a separate section of code underneath the original. Thanks.

Comment: I have added the model

Comment: ok but you haven't added the code which calls the GetCarLinesResponse method. That's where you need to make a change.

Comment: So which line of code is throwing the `implicitly convert type WS.Car.Model.Carline[] to WEBAPI.Model.CarLineReponse` error then??

Comment: the return is throwing the error //return CAR.CARline;

Comment: No, that line on its own doesn't throw the error. Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FV49vt . There are no exceptions. I don't know what you did wrong, but it's not in the code I've shown. Double-check that you've done everything exactly as I've written above.